# Designing and memory allocation buffer memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, buffer

My application has 3 layers -downlayer, middlelayer and upperlayer. downlayer and upperlayer are decoupled. Data passes either this way upperlayer -> middlelayer -> downlayer, or this way downlayer -> middlelayer->upperlayer.

My code look like this:
UpperLayer.c

```
#include <middlelayer.h>

int upperReaddownData()
{
    DATA_ST* readFromdown_ptr = (DATA_ST*)malloc(sizeof(DATA_ST*));
    if(readFromdown_ptr != NULL)
    { 
      int retVal = GetFunction(readFromdown_ptr, UP);
      if (retVal == 0) {
          bool value;
          memcpy(&value, readFromdown_ptr->continousData, sizeof(bool));
              printf("Data read %s\t",
                  value ? "true" : "false");
              printf("\n");
          }
          // I get error here
      free(readFromdown_ptr);
      return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int UpperWritedownData()
{
    bool  random = rand() % 2;
    DATA_ST* dumpTodown_ptr = (DATA_ST*)malloc(sizeof(DATA_ST*));
    if (dumpTodown_ptr != NULL) {
        size_t size_data = (size_t)sizeof(bool);
        memcpy(dumpTodown_ptr->continousData, &random, size_data);
        // size of data has to be mentioned while writing to memory
        dumpTodown_ptr->packetSize = size_data;
        int retVal = SetFunction(dumpTodown_ptr, DOWN);
        // i get error here
        free(dumpTodown_ptr);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

middlelayer.h

```
#define UP 0x00
#define DOWN 0x01

#define BUFFER_SIZE 2

typedef struct
{
    size_t packetSize;
    uint8_t continousData[80];
}DATA_ST;

typedef struct
{
    bool isDataAlreadyRead;
    DATA_ST Data;
}PACKET_HEADER_ST;

int Init();
int GetFunction(DATA_ST* packet, uint8_t target);
int SetFunction(DATA_ST* packet, uint8_t target);
int DeInit();
```

middlelayer.c

```
   #include<middlelayer.h>

#define COPY_MEMORY(Dst,Src,Size) memcpy(Dst,Src,Size)

static PACKET_HEADER_ST* BUFFER[BUFFER_SIZE];

int Init()
{
    uint8_t instance;
    for (instance = 0; instance < BUFFER_SIZE; instance++) {
        BUFFER[instance] = (PACKET_HEADER_ST*)calloc(1,sizeof(PACKET_HEADER_ST));
        if (BUFFER[instance] != NULL)
        {
            BUFFER[instance]->isDataAlreadyRead = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int GetFunction(DATA_ST* packet,uint8_t target)
{
    DATA_ST* currPacket = NULL;
    if (BUFFER[target]->isDataAlreadyRead == false)
    {
        // not getting how to use memcpy properly
        //currPacket = (DATA_ST*)&BUFFER[target]->Data;
        //COPY_MEMORY(packet->continousData, currPacket->continousData, sizeof(BUFFER[target]->Data.packetSize));
        //packet->packetSize = currPacket->packetSize;
        //BUFFER[target]->isDataAlreadyRead = true;
        *packet = BUFFER[target]->Data;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int SetFunction(DATA_ST* packet, uint8_t target)
{
    //COPY_MEMORY(BUFFER[target]->Data.continousData, packet->continousData,sizeof(packet->packetSize));
    //BUFFER[target]->Data.packetSize = packet->packetSize;
    //BUFFER[target]->isDataAlreadyRead = false;
    BUFFER[target]->Data = *packet;
    BUFFER[target]->isDataAlreadyRead = false;
    return 0;
}

int DeInit()
{
    uint8_t instance;
    for (instance = 0; instance < BUFFER_SIZE; instance++) {    
        free(BUFFER[instance]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

lowerlayer.c

#include<middlelayer.h>

```
int downReadUpData(void)

{
    DATA_ST* readFromDown_ptr = (DATA_ST*)malloc(sizeof(DATA_ST*));
    if (readFromDown_ptr != NULL)
    {
        int retVal = GetFunction(readFromDown_ptr,DOWN);
        if (retVal == 0) {
            bool mybool;
            
            memcpy(&mybool, readFromDown_ptr->continousData,readFromDown_ptr->packetSize);
            // do something with data
            
        }
        // i get error here
        free(readFromDown_ptr); 
        readFromDown_ptr = NULL;
        return retVal;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

//send dummy data to Up
int downWriteUpData(void)
{
    static bool race_b = false;
    DATA_ST* dumpToUp_ptr = (DATA_ST*)malloc(sizeof(DATA_ST*));
    if (dumpToUp_ptr != NULL) {
        size_t size_data = (size_t)sizeof(bool);
        memcpy(dumpToUp_ptr->continousData, &race_b, size_data);
        // size of data has to be mentioned while writing to memory
        dumpToUp_ptr->packetSize = size_data;
        int retVal = SetFunction(dumpToUp_ptr, UP);
        // i get error here
        free(dumpToUp_ptr);
        dumpToUp_ptr = NULL;
        race_b = !race_b;
        return retVal;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I call UpperWritedownData function, it calls SetFunction, then i call downReadUpData Function and read the data passed by Upper layer.

I want to design the middlelayer like this : you pass the data of any datatype to the middlelayer(uint8_t array can hold any datatype), during Init ,the middlelayer is allocated some memory and i have the pointer of `BUFFER[Up]->Data` or `BUFFER[DOWN]->Data` and these pointers are constant and should not change throughout the program. Now upper/down layer gives data (SetFunction) , i dump it in my preallocated memory, then after some time, down/upper asks the data i copy the data from my preallocated memory and give it.Now I just need to store the recent data hence i have not implemented queues also i am overwriting and once the data is read , i dont care about it and I have to discard it.

What I tried:
I tried using memcpy and copy the pointer to `BUFFER[x]->Data` and I have commented that part of code as you can see.It did not work because memcpy copies the pointer to `BUFFER[target]->Data`but i wanted to copy just the contents.When I tried to use free(pointer), i get heap corruption error message.I am having trouble in using memory allocation. Kindly provide inputs.

Comment: Aside: To help debug and since `BUFFER[instance];` is global, after `free(BUFFER[instance]);`, also `BUFFER[instance] = NULL`.

Comment: Well, if at all possible, I would copy nothing except pointers and communicate everything on producer-consumer queues, (that I am 100% sure work correctly).  Malloc at the top, free at the bottom.  Either that or malloc/create a pool of structs/objects at startup and store their pointers/instances in a pool queue.  Copying bulk data, vars named 'race' and suchlike scare me, (if only because such a design is imp...very difficult to test fully and so has a fitness-for-purpose shortfall).

Comment: I dont need a queue,the producer data has to be overwritten and I don't need thread safety too.I don't want to make the program complicated.How to implement  producer consumer in such place?

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  First, it is missing a `#include` statements for `stddef.h`  `stdbool.h`  `stdint.h`  `stdlib.h`  `string.h`  `stdio.h`  The `homegrown` header files are missing 'include guards'.  The struct definitions are missing a `tag` name.  (`tag` names are needed so debuggers can easily display the fields within the struct instances). You say the functions are not 'reentrant', so why use `malloc()` and `free()` when you can simply declare the needed buffers and use them as needed

Comment: the `SetFunction()` returns a value, but that value is never used

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding, (the compiler does not care)  Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{',  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: regarding statements like: `DATA_ST* readFromDown_ptr = (DATA_ST*)malloc(sizeof(DATA_ST*));`   1) all this allocates is a pointer, not an instance of the DATA_ST struct  2) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).  Suggest removing that cast

Comment: the #include are included in header files, i thought it would increase the question size, so have not included main and other files.thanks for the inputs

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in this `malloc`:

```
DATA_ST* readFromdown_ptr = (DATA_ST*)malloc(sizeof(DATA_ST*));
```

You define `readFromdown_ptr` as a pointer to `DATA_ST`. So you want to make it point to a memory block that can hold a `DATA_ST` but you only allocate memory for a pointer to `DATA_ST` because you do `sizeof(DATA_ST*)`.

Change it to:

```
DATA_ST* readFromdown_ptr = malloc(sizeof(DATA_ST));
```

or better.. change it to:

```
DATA_ST* readFromdown_ptr = malloc(sizeof *readFromdown_ptr);
```

The same applies to the line:

```
DATA_ST* dumpToUp_ptr = (DATA_ST*)malloc(sizeof(DATA_ST*));
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem.You have any suggestions how can I improve this producer consumer  design?